# sed, JSON and curly braces

Tags: json, bash, sed, curly-braces

I have a file that includes some text before a JSON data.
I'm trying to get rid of the text and just keep the JSON so I'm using:

```
sed -n '/{"data"/,$p' myfile.txt
```

The result of this command works fine in the terminal - it returns just the JSON but when I push the output to a file with the following command:

```
sed -n '/{"data"/,$p' myfile.txt > output.json
```

then the "output.json" still has some text. I understand that I have an issue with properly escaping the curly braces and sed treats my {"data" as a regex but I don't know how I can avoid this.

Comment: please edit your Q to include a minumal set of of JSON that will illustrate the problem. Don't make use guess;-)

Comment: Don't use line-oriented tools to manipulate structured data.  There are good JSON tools which properly understand the input format and take care not to wreck it.

Comment: @shellter - here is a nice example of what I have as myfile.txt: https://code.google.com/p/droidbox/issues/detail?id=59

I just want to get the JSON data.

Comment: @tripleee - I know :) but first I need to extract just the JSON data from a file that includes also a nonJSON text.

Comment: The reasons your `sed` is not succeeding notwithstanding, a simple workaround would be `awk '/^\{"data"/{p=1}p' myfile.txt >output.json`

Comment: no reason that a redirection like '>' change the behaviour of your sed. This is the same myfile.txt in both case and same environment for your command line ? With a `| tee output.json` you have same terminal and file content ?

Comment: @tripleee - thanks but this command returns null in my case :(

Comment: @NeronLeVelu - when I do:
sed -n '/{"data"/,$p' myfile.txt | tee output.json
then I get exactly the same output.json like in my original command.

Comment: One more thing - the text that is left - each line starts with a dot - does that change anything?

Comment: maybe a sample of IN and OUT will help because `>` and `|tee` should do the same to the destination file unless the session has a different context (ex batch from a crontab, via ssh, ...) and the content of the file is interpretated differently in this case (sed do the same job in both situation)

Comment: After some more investigations I found out that the script that generates the original "myfile.txt" (JSON + some text) adds special characters. I guess the fact that these characters exist in the file make the system think that this is a binary file and hence I have my issues.

Answer (score 0):

After some more investigations I found out that the script (not mine) that generates the original "myfile.txt" (JSON + some text) adds special characters. I guess the fact that these characters exist in the file make the system think that this is a binary file and hence I have my issues.

When I did "cat -v output.json" I could see the additional text which is not displayed if I just do "cat output.json".

As a workaround I modified the original script not to add some of the additional text.

With the modified script, the generated "myfile.txt" can be parsed with sed and your suggestions above work great.

Thanks to anyone who contributed and spent their time trying to help me out.